# Noun (or alternative) of thought-provoking?

Tags: phrases, nouns, vocabulary, synonyms

I'm planning to start a blog. And before every post, I'm planning to add how thought-provoking I think that post is.

So I was thinking about something that I can call `thought-provoking-ness level`. However, I don't think `thought-provoking-ness` is an English word. So my question is:

Is there a noun for `thought-provoking`, and if there is not. What could be an alternative?

Comment: "Muse factor"?  Considering both the verb and noun meanings of the word.

Comment: @Wudang. I like your proposal, why don't you post it?

Comment: Flattery will get you anywhere!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about *mental stimulation*?

Answer (score 7):

"Muse factor"? Considering both the verb and noun meanings of the word.
Noun form :"the goddess or the power regarded as inspiring a poet, artist, thinker, or the like."
Verb form : "to reflect (about) or ponder (on), usually in silence "

Answer (score 5):

I guess it depends on how informal you want to be. Blogs usually are so I would go with something like ***Headscratcher Factor***, slightly poetic and descriptive!

Answer (score 4):

In computer science, the term *[complexity](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/complexity)* often is used to refer to a measure of how much work a problem takes to solve.  If that term is less interesting than you want, consider the term *[twistiness](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/twistiness)*.  Note, *twistyness* does not have a wiktionary entry and might as well be avoided unless you aren't picky about neologisms.  But if you aren't picky, also consider *convolvity*, to refer to how convoluted a problem is, or *intriguity*, to refer to how intriguing a problem is.   You might also use a little pipe icon, and refer to one-pipe, [two-pipe](http://forums.wowace.com/showthread.php?t=18034), etc. problems.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to stick with *thought provoking* you could expand it to *thought provocation level* or *thought provoking level*. If you want to sound all fancy then you could go for *neural excitation*.

Answer (score 1):

In the provided context, I would suggest something like *'[Zen](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/zen) score'* or a more esoteric alternative in *'[kōan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%8Dan) score'*. [Kōan/koan is defined](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/koan) in most dictionaries. There is the added bonus of these terms--which imply something along the lines of provoking thought or simply, meditation--themselves provoking thought or at least a look-up in a dictionary :)

Answer (score 1):

Intrigue level, provocativity (not a word, but at least a nice made-up one). Depends on the type of blog, I guess.

Answer (score 1):

**Insightfulness.**

When something is insightful it has the effect of being thought provoking. So although it is not a direct equivalent, it gets you the meaning you want in one word.

Answer (score 0):

Thought-provoking-ness, sounds awesome! It's kind of bulky, but in a cool way like Superman. Just make the word up, dress it in T-shirt with an S on it. Maybe give it an honorary title:

> "This post has a score of 8 in Awesome Thought-Provoking-Ness", or
>   " Thought-Provoking-Ness of Doom™ ", or
>   "Thought-Provoking-Ness Like You'll Think About It Forever"

okay, so the last one is maybe a bit long, but yeah, you get the idea. Just make it up.

Answer (score 0):

**Scintillating** means [brilliantly lively, stimulating, or witty](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scintillating) .  The noun form, **scintillation** means a flash of light but also [a brilliant outburst](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/scintillation). While this is often associated with wit, it may convey what you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Thought provocation** would be the event of provoking a thought, which occurs in the thinker.

**Thought provocativeness** would be the quality of provoking thoughts, which occurs in the provoker.